# Cannot change style of UINavigationBar when using scrollViewDidScroll on separate View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have three view controllers embedded within a `UINavigationController`. `FirstViewController` navigates to `SecondTableViewController`, which navigates to `ThirdDetailViewController`.

The problem I am having is when customising the style of the `status bar` and `UINavigationBar` using the `scrollViewDidScroll` method within the `SecondTableViewController` it also override the other view controllers within the stack that come after it as well as all status bar styles.

Does anybody know how I can prevent the scrollViewDidScroll method from effecting other view controllers within the stack ?

**FirstViewController**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()       
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true

}
```

**SecondTableViewController**

I change the style of the navigation depending on how far down the user has scrolled to either blend in or stand out from the content.

The style of other view controllers change to whichever style is set in the method.

```
 override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let color = colorWheel()

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > -60) {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = color.appColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = color.appColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true

    } else {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    }
}
```

**ThirdDetailViewController**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()       
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Navigation properties from within the `viewDidAppear` method as well.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()       
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by (UIKit framework) design.

Your hierarchy is like this:

- **Navigation Controller** (with a navigation bar)

hosting inside its stack

- **FirstViewController**
- **SecondTableViewController**
- **ThirdDetailViewController**

Any UIViewController subclass that means also your controllers inherits a property called `.navigationController.` This simply points to whichever navigation controller hosts the view controller.

That means all three controllers you have point to THE SAME navigation controller.
It's logical that it doesn't matter WHERE you do changes to `.navigationController` - because it's always **the same and one and only navigation controller with one and only navigation bar**, if you push or pop any view controller to the navigation stack, you will still see the latest styling you applied for the navigation bar.

The solution for you is to handle the navigation bar styling EXPLICITLY in EACH controller.

BONUS TRACK:

You can extract the navigation bar styling into a UIViewController extension.
You could have a method called `setNavigationStyle`, define an enum NavigationStyle with some style cases, implement the style for each case inside the method, and then in any view controller inside `viewWillAppear`..just call `setNavigationStyle: .Dark`or whatever.
This will scale nicely because you might have 3 style but 14 controllers. This way you prevent duplication of style implementation all over the place and make code reusable.

Comment: I was already changing the style from within the controllers, however I have accepted an answer for changing it within `viewDidAppear` as well, I was setting it in `viewWillAppear` but the style was overridden when loaded. I will definitely use an extension to easily mage the styles.

Comment: Doing it in viewDidApear doesn't make much sense from UX perspective. The method name is obvious...the view already did appear. I hardly can imagine a scenario where a controller appears and when everything calms down suddenly the style of navigation bar changes. 
Perhaps you might rephrase your question then because you are asking why a change in 1 controller affects the bar for others. Just moving the effect to apply a bit later  in time doesn't alter the fundamental problem in any way. Or did I miss something? :/

Comment: Yes, I thought the exact same thing. What I found was that the style of the navigation was set during `viewWillLoad` and `ViewWillAppear` but changed when the view loaded to the style of the second view controller. Which was weird, but setting the style for the navigation in `viewDidAppear` prevented the style from being overridden. Paying close attention when segueing you can see a glitch in the navigation when this took place therefore I found the navigation was changed once the view had loaded. Only when the answer was given did I notice the glitch when not setting styles in viewDidLoad