# Segue from one view controller embedded within UINavigationController to another UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` as my root controller, but then I segue from one view controller to another `UINavigationController`.

But when segueing from one view controller which is embedded within a UINavigationController to another UINavigationController the push segue comes from the bottom, presuming it is segueing as a popover. I tried using a show detail segue but still not luck.

Why is this occurring and how can I segue from one to the other using a push/replace segue ?

PS: Is this happening because the `UINavigationControllers` conflict and overrides the segue as a `popover` ? The reason I am using two separate navigation controllers is because the style from the previous view overrides the style of the detail view, i posted a separate question about that [Cannot change style of UINavigationBar when using scrollViewDidScroll on separate View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241914/cannot-change-style-of-uinavigationbar-when-using-scrollviewdidscroll-on-separat)

Comment: you probably shouldn't push a `UINavigationController` onto another `UINavigationController`. the whole point of `UINavigationController` is that you only need _one_ that manages all the view controllers it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push segue occurs only within one navigation controller. It's how it implements 'show' type segue. Making 'show' segue from navigation controller to another navigation controller is not what Xcode drawing tool considered as 'pushing'. It interprets it as popover by default.